# why the chrome mobile debug mode set a much larger width of the html body rather than the device width?

Tags: html, css, mobile, google-chrome-devtools, debug-mode

I have an image element in an html body which width is 440 px and height is 840 px. Everything works as expected until I open the chrome debug mode to simulate it display in mobile device.

[screenshot with body width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RbCK.jpg)

As the screenshot shows, the simulator suppose to 375 px width. But is somehow become 964 px width. There is no any extra css script or js script there. Just a simple html with one image.[screenshot with image width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lV5s.jpg)

Answer (score 7):

We found that you need to have the following in your header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

There are more details about it here: [www.sitepoint.com/media-queries-width-vs-device-width/](https://www.sitepoint.com/media-queries-width-vs-device-width/)

Comment: It would be more helpful to provide those details here, especially in the event that the link breaks...

Answer (score 1):

According to your screenshot chrome is showing the correct device size which is 375 x 812. It would have been better if you clicked on the `img` in your screenshot. So not exactly sure what you need. It appears the issue is with the image. If the width of your image is 440px try this in your CSS.

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {

 body img{
   max-width: 100%;
 }

}
```

Comment: Chrome is showing the correct device size. but if you look at the right down corner, the actual size of the body is 964 px width.